# BC42356 - Async method lacks 'Await' for function returning Task(Of DataTable)

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I call a function which returns a `Task(Of DataTable)` like this (pseudo-code):

```vb
dgv.DataSource = Await GetDataTable()
```

My function `GetDataTable()` looks like this:

```vb
Async Function GetDataTable() As Task(Of DataTable)

    'Connection objects etc
    OracleDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Table")

    Return ds.Tables("Table")

End Function
```

However, I am getting the warning `"This async method lacks 'Await' operators and so will run synchronously."` on the above function.

Which makes sense but surely this is a very common situation as you cannot `Await` a DataAdapter.

My calling method is async and awaiting the function `GetDataTable()` so the return type must be `Task(Of DataTable)`.

In order to do that the function must be async (otherwise I get a tyoe error on `Return ds.Tables("Table")` because you cannot convert from DataTable to Task(Of DataTable).

Should I just ignore this warning or should I be doing this another way?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There's nothing to await in that method. `Async` won't make a method run asynchronously. It's syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to await already running asynchronous operations.

Comment: I guess that's the point I'm making. I don't need the code within the function to run asynchronously (because it can't), but I need to the function to be async so that I can return `Task(Of DataTable)`. Is there a way I should do this which avoid the warning or do I just ignore the warning (which makes me nervous).

Comment: If `OracleDataAdapter` has a `FillAsync` method, use `Await `OracleDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Table")`. If not, you should probably wrap this code in a `Task.Run` and return the task directly without awaiting it, eg `Function GetDataTable.... Return Task.Run(Function() ActualImplementation())`. You could also fake it by returning a completed task with [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8) but that would still be a synchronous operation

Comment: You have things muddled.  If method A is declared `Async` and method B wants to await it then method B must be declared `Async` too.  That's not what's happening in your situation.  The fact that the method that calls `GetDataTable` is declared `Async` is irrelevant to `GetDataTable`.  If `GetDataTable` doesn't await anything then it should not be declared `Async` and you just call it the same as any other method.

Comment: `I don't need the code within the function to run asynchronously ...but I need to the function to be async` that's self-contradictory. It either is or isn't. Again, `async` doesn't make a method async. It's only *syntactic sugar* that allows the use of `Await`. Callers want something that returns a `Task`, they don't even see that `Async` keyword.

Comment: It should be obvious that an `Async` method can call a regular synchronous method without awaiting it by the fact that you're calling `Fill`, which is not `Async`, in `GetDataTable`.  Just do that same thing in the method that calls `GetDataTable`, i.e. call it like any other method and get rid of the `Async` declaration.

Comment: Faking it by returning a completed tasks would remove the error but result in a *very* unpleasant surprise for anyone calling your method by freezing the UI or web server request thread. Using `Task.Run` would use one extra thread. In a busy web app that's not desirable. If the caller expects the method to be really asynchronous, *don't* use SqlDataAdapter. Use ExecuteReaderAsync to execute  the command asynchronously at least and load the DataTable from the reader with [DataTable.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the comments both. I think my original misunderstanding was that calling `dgv.DataSource = Await GetDataTable()` on an async method that lacked `Await` was the same as just calling `dgv.DataSource = GetDataTable()` (if it were all synchronous). My real issue is that my application's slowest part is database queries (it has to do a lot and some of them take a while) so I'm looking for ways to fire the queries at the same time and handle the results as they become available; I thought async was the way to do that but I think now perhaps it's not.

Comment: Async methods won't speed up your queries but it will allow you to execute more than one at the same time, assuming your connection supports it.  The thing is though, you then need to NOT await each call.  You need to call all the methods first without awaiting them, then you can await all the `Tasks` they return.  If you await each one then it's much like calling synchronous methods.  You need to kick off each one and then wait for them all to complete as a group, for which you can call `Task.WaitAll`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep your method asynchronous because of some API you need to comply with, try this:

```
Function GetDataTable() As Task(Of DataTable)

    'Connection objects etc
    OracleDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Table")

    Return Task.FromResult(ds.Tables("Table"))

End Function
```